# Does the ARM processor have invalidate queue?

Tags: multithreading, arm, cpu-architecture, processor

Does the ARM processor have invalidate queue?
I looked up the ARM Architecture Reference Manaul[https://www.scss.tcd.ie/~waldroj/3d1/arm_arm.pdf], but it did NOT mention 'invalidate queue'(it did mention 'write buffer'), so does this mean
that ARM don't have invalidate queue?